# Docks are all the same

Tags: gnome

Ok, so, I was screwing around with customization of the doc a bit; editing the CSS, using dconf editor; but when I downloaded the extension "Dash to dock" everything broke. dconf editor no longer works and whenever I switch shell themes the dock is always the same. I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using? I do not see a question here. I do see a statement that you broke it.

Comment: I am using 20.04, and my question is how do I fix this? I want to be able to use themes and dconf editor.

Comment: Please edit the question and add this info. Based on what you have in your question. Which is no details at all. Like what did you do exactly, I would suggest reinstall.